# Backup files from linux vm in Azure

Tags: azure, backup

I have been tasked with backing up certain files the exist on a Linux VM in azure to an azure backup vault.

I'm following the follwing documentation :-

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/backup-configure-vault/

However i can't see a backp agent for a linux box?

Am i missing something?

T

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a backup agent for Linux. You would use your standard backup/restore strategy here, for example rsync if it's just files or Bacula for something else. However, if the files absolutely need to be in the vault (say, because there are Windows Server VMs that need to use them) then I would suggest you use [Azure Files](http://blog.elastocloud.org/2014/06/using-azure-file-service-on-linux.html) to get the files out of Linux, then back them up from the Windows VMs. You can of course scp them, or use other methods. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I had to do in a CentOS VM (credit goes to [this serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/706421)).

Install the agent in the VM via SSH terminal:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/WALinuxAgent/WALinuxAgent-2.0.12/waagent  
chmod +x waagent
sudo cp waagent /usr/sbin
sudo /usr/sbin/waagent -install -verbose
sudo service waagent restart
```

Then I had to run the following cmdlets in an Azure PowerShell window, in order to flag the agent as installed:

```
$vm = Get-AzureVM -ServiceName 'myAzureServiceName' -Name 'myAzureVMName'
$vm.GetInstance().ProvisionGuestAgent = $true
Update-AzureVM -ServiceName 'myAzureServiceName' –Name 'myAzureVMName' -VM $vm.VM
```